# Run Command on Remote Host From Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, ssh

How can I run a command on an Azure VM host from an Azure DevOps Pipeline?  I tried setting up an ssh service connection, but that fails with this:

"##[error]Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: Error: All configured authentication methods failed"

I can connect from my laptop, so I don't understand how this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Azure DevOps Service Connection, enter a Private Key (optional), you now have a VM `id_rsa_pub`.
2. Login to your VM, copy the VM SSH `id_rsa_pub` into the VM `authorized_keys`; if you don't have the `id_rsa`, use the command [`ssh-keygen`](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/keygen).
3. Try again.